# Refresh the page in seconds by taking the time to refresh entered user in PHP

Tags: php, html

I need to refresh the page in seconds , but I want to refresh the time value entered by the user.
This code is correct but run one time. I want to run it as long as the user page out.

I dont know how to write a ring for.

This is my HTML code

```
<form class="form-inline" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">Refresh page by secondes</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="refresh-time">
    </div>  
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-pencil" ></i> Apply</button>
</form>
```

This is my PHP code

```
        <?php
        $pagename = 'لیست کلیه تماس ها';        
        require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/header.php'; 

        if(isset($_POST['btnreferesh']))
        {
            $p_call_loges->pages( '20' );
        }

        if(isset($_POST['refresh-time']))
        {

            header("Refresh:$time");

        }


    ?>  
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h2 class="page-header">لیست گزارش تماس ها</h2>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel panel-yellow">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="panel-title pull-right">
                            <i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> نمایش اطلاعات ثبت شده
                        </div>
                        <form method="POST">
                            <button type="submit" name="btnreferesh" class="btn btn-default pull-left"><i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i> بازسازی فرم</button>
                        </form>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="text-right">نام و نام خانوادگی مبدا</th>
                                    <th class="text-right">شماره موبایل مبدا</th>
                                    <th class="text-right">نام و نام خانوادگی مقصد</th>
                                    <th class="text-right">شماره موبایل مقصد </th>
                                    <th class="text-right">زمان شروع</th>
                                    <th class="text-right">مدت زمان مکالمه</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php $arr = $p_call_loges->pages( '20' ); if( $arr ) { foreach( $arr as $row ) { ?>
                                <tr class="odd gradeX">
                                    <td><?php echo $row['source_name_family']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['source_mobile_num']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['destination_name_family']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['destination_mobile_num']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['call_time']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['duration']; ?> دقیقه</td>
                                </tr>   
                                <?php } } else { ?>
                                    <?php echo all_noting; ?>
                                <?php } ?>                                                                       
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <!-- /.table-responsive -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel-body -->
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <form class="form-inline" method="POST">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="text">بازسازی صفحه براساس ثانیه</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="refresh-time">
                            </div>  
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-pencil" ></i> ثبت</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel-footer -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.panel -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
    <!-- /#page-wrapper -->
    <?php
        require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/footer.php';     
    ?>
```

Comment: That's not how HTTP works. Sending infinite `Refresh` headers until the browser runs out of memory will not trigger infinite redirections.

Answer (score 1):

Use your formular to let the user enter the timeout. With the following PHP-Snippet a html-refresh is inserted in your html code. Make sure the output is placed in the head tag. Add the given timeout as get parameter in the refresh URL. With the following refresh the PHP-Snippet receives the timeout again and the html-refresh is inserted again to.

Because your formular sends the data with post, you have to use the $_REQUEST variable, which contains the data from $_POST, $_GET and $_COOKIE.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['refresh-time']))
{
    $time = $_REQUEST['refresh-time'];
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="'.$time.'; URL=http://www.example.com/yourPage.php?refresh-time='.$time.'">';
}
```

Or you change your form to GET and use $_GET['refresh-time'].

Comment: Thank you for answer, but i want user entered  refresh time

Comment: @davOOd What's the problem them? This answer is based in your own code.

Comment: The timeout is entered by the user. I edited my answer to make this more clear.

Comment: Thank you for answer, this code run one time . I want after entering the refresh constantly be repeated.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike FTP or IRC, HTTP is a stateless protocol. In simple words that means that the browser stablishes a network connection, asks for a resource, receives the response and closes the connection (this is not strictly true in all cases but it's good enough by now). Additionally, a response can only request one redirection because it doesn't make sense to redirect to more than one place.

So sending HTTP headers in an infinite loop will just make the browser timeout or crash.

Your page has to redirect once and include the timeout information in next page load. If you want a pure server-side solution you need to transmit the information in either of these:

1. As GET parameter in the redirection URL
2. As cookie
3. As session data

I'd go for #1 since it's the only mechanism that's tab-aware.

```
// Simplified untested code
$url = 'http://example.com/foo.php';
$timeout = null;
if (isset($_POST['refresh-time']) && $_POST['refresh-time']>0) {
    $timeout = $_POST['refresh-time'];
} elseif (isset($_GET['refresh-time']) && $_GET['refresh-time']>0) {
    $timeout = $_GET['refresh-time'];
}
if (!is_null($timeout)) {
   header(sprintf('Refresh: %2$d; URL=$1$s?refresh-time=%2$d', $url, $timeout));
   exit;
}
// HTML comes here (form included)
```